# Prove that V is a subset of $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that $V ⊆ (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$ for a subspace V of $\mathbb R^n$?

It makes sense intuitively, but I don't know how to do it mathematically. If anyone could give me a hint on how to start, that'd be great.

Comment: Isn't  $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}=V?$

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Yes, that's what I'm trying to prove eventually.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan : In a finite dimensional inner product space, or for a closed subspace $V$ of a separable Hilbert space, yes, that is true. But I am not sure if you have equality in general infinite dimensional inner product spaces.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan : In fact, probably not. If $V$ is a non-closed  subspace of a Hilbert space, then $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}$ contains the closure of $V$, so strictly contains $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Let $v\in V$ be a vector.

Step 2: Set $U=V^\perp$, and prove that $v\in U^\perp$.  You will use the definition of $\perp$ repeatedly.

Step 3: Since $v\in V$ was arbitrary, this proves $V\subseteq U^\perp=(V^\perp)^\perp$.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.